# Display and link custom attribute in product page mangento 2

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, custom, page

I have installed magneto 2.4.5 and trying to show manufacturer above product title .
I have set custom theme using Luma as base , I have found many example of showing custom attribute on the product page , but none actually show any attribute on my page. I am not sure if there are some changes in latest version of magento 2 or I m doing something wrong.
also I Like to know if is possible to link manufacturer to either search result or Custom CMS page.
I appreciate any help with this little matter.
Thanks.

I am using following code
in catalog_product_view.xml

````
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
     <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
         <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.attribute.custom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute/custom.phtml">
             <arguments>
                 <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Your Custom Attribute Title</argument>
             </arguments>
         </block>
     </referenceContainer>
 </body>
 </page>```

and custom.phthml

```<?php
$product = $block->getProduct();
$attrData = $product->getData('{attributeCode}');
$blockTitle = $this->getData('title');
if (trim($attrData) !== "") : ?>
 <div class="product-full-width-section">
     <h2 class="product-section-title"><?= $blockTitle; ?></h2>
     <?php echo $attrData; ?>
 </div>
<?php endif; ?>```

Checking magento 2 system.log file , i noticed warning . about template path 
`product/view/attribute/custom.phtml`
I have created this path as shown in above code and i have modified to different paths , but I keep getting this warning. 

This is the warning in system.log file. 
```Invalid template file: 'Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute/custom.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Catalog' block's name: 'product.attribute.custom'```
````

Comment: plz add custom.phtml file path

Comment: typo here . it is custom.phtml in my folder. i also used blow code and as i mentioned on post , it works but it outputs ID number.

Comment: you can use getAttributeText('attributeCode');

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that before . using getAttributeText nothing shows up on the page . even ID number disappears.

Comment: can try getManufacturer(); as well!

Comment: i have tired that as well, dose not display anything. I am not sure why i have Invalid template file: 'Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom.phtml ? in my system.log . my template override looks correct and many files are loaded correctly from this custom theme.

Comment: ok , finally got it working. one issue was spelling error on a folder and i had to change the above code from getdata() to getAttributeText() to show the text and not ID.

Answer (score 0):

i use this code that i found in my catalog_view.xml

````
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.attribute.{attributeCode}" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">get{attributeCode}</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">{attributeCode}</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Any Custom Attribute Label</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">Any CSS Class Name</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>```

Now this kinda works. problem with this code , is that it shows ID and not attribute Name ( manufacturer ) . any suggestion ?
````